Ethernet not working on Pi5
New from Box, Pi5.  No config changes on install. Using Rasberry Pi OS 64-bit.  WiFi connection works well.  But, cannot get Ethernet connection. Green light on. But when I turn the WiFi connection off, OS says "requesting an ethernet network connection."  But, then times out. On the Network Edit there is no IP address for the ethernet adapter.  The Ethernet cable is connected to a switch.  This setup works well with other hardware.
How do I debug this problem?

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

Welcome -- please edit into the question what the other end of the ethernet cable is attached to.

I have a similar setup with a Pi 5, had the same problem. For me, the solution was to re-install the OS. I installed Raspberry PI OS full, it then worked.
